# Jboss flushing component applied

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Hello i have a problem when i deplay ear , whe i induce o web xhtml i have INFo in jboss server

> 10:09:02,196 ERROR [STDERR] 2012-09-27 10:09:02
>   com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet refresh INFO:
>   Facelet[/layout/template.xhtml] was modified @ 10:09:02, flushing
>   component applied @ 09:58:57

I didnt change configuration in jboss or in system . I worked 4-5h and I had this info.... I dont want to use REFRESH-PERIOD someone know oder resolve?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a time issue.Workstation where application Server located has DateTime settings - 2 hours less then current time (wrong clock settings). So after deploying our application on it we receive such exception because xhtml files creation time has been greater than current time on workstation.

When deploying a new EAR or war created from a machine with time settings different from that of the server where application is deployed, flushing of the JSF components can happen.

Comment: Ok but in my second project evrything is ok ... do you know what should I change in my computer settings to fix it?

Comment: To fix this problem add REFRESH_PERIOD to the web.xml.REFRESH_PERIOD indicates, When a page is requested, what interval in seconds should the compiler check for changes.